# clang makefile "ar: no archive members specified"

Tags: c, gcc, makefile, clang, unix-ar

I refactor some C code and I try to compile it as a lib on clang on mac instead of gcc on linux.

First of all if I just run `make` command I got an error at the first file compile:
`+++ Compiling [sys_msg.c]
clang: error: unsupported argument '-adhlns=../../src/sys_msg.lst' to option 'Wa,'`

So I remove the `-Wa,-adhlns=$(<:.c=.lst)` option that create this error.

After that everything seems to compile but the assembly of the last .a file fail, and I don't understand why.

Here is my make output :

```
+++ Creation of [../../hal/stub/obj]
+++ Dependencies of [hal.c]
+++ Dependencies of [target.c]
+++ Dependencies of [robus.c]
+++ Dependencies of [reception.c]
+++ Dependencies of [sys_msg.c]
+++ Compiling [sys_msg.c]
+++ Compiling [reception.c]
+++ Compiling [robus.c]
+++ Compiling [target.c]
+++ Compiling [hal.c]
ar -rv ../../hal/stub/libstub.a 
ar: no archive members specified
usage:  ar -d [-TLsv] archive file ...
    ar -m [-TLsv] archive file ...
    ar -m [-abiTLsv] position archive file ...
    ar -p [-TLsv] archive [file ...]
    ar -q [-cTLsv] archive file ...
    ar -r [-cuTLsv] archive file ...
    ar -r [-abciuTLsv] position archive file ...
    ar -t [-TLsv] archive [file ...]
    ar -x [-ouTLsv] archive [file ...]
make: *** [../../hal/stub/libstub.a] Error 1
```

Here is my makefile:

```
# make all = Make software and program
# make clean = Clean out built project files.
# make program = Download the hex file to the device, using avrdude.  Please
#                customize the avrdude settings below first!
# make docs = compile with doxygen the code documentation

# Maximum I2C speed (HZ)
SCLFREQ = 400000

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Tools
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Set DEBUG variable for once if not coming from command line
ifndef DEBUG
DEBUG = 0
endif

# Tool suffix when cross-compiling
CROSS_COMPILE ?=

# Compilation tools
CC = $(CROSS_COMPILE)gcc
AR = $(CROSS_COMPILE)ar
SIZE = $(CROSS_COMPILE)size
STRIP = $(CROSS_COMPILE)strip
OBJCOPY = $(CROSS_COMPILE)objcopy
OBJDUMP = $(CROSS_COMPILE)objdump
SIZE = $(CROSS_COMPILE)size
GDB = $(CROSS_COMPILE)gdb
NM = $(CROSS_COMPILE)nm

ROOT_PATH = ../..
HAL_PATH = $(ROOT_PATH)/hal/$(BOARD)
DOC_PATH = $(ROOT_PATH)/../extra/Docs

# Doxygen configuration file name
DOXYFILE = $(ROOT_PATH)/../extra/.Doxyfile

OBJ_PATH = $(HAL_PATH)/obj
OUTPUT_NAME = lib$(BOARD)
OUTPUT_FILE_PATH = $(HAL_PATH)/$(OUTPUT_NAME).a

#|---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
#| Source files                                                                          |
#|---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
include ../sources.mk

#|---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
#| Extract file names and path                                                           |
#|---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
PROJ_ASRCS   = $(filter %.s,$(foreach file,$(SOURCES),$(file)))
PROJ_ASRCS  += $(filter %.S,$(foreach file,$(SOURCES),$(file)))
PROJ_CSRCS   = $(filter %.c,$(foreach file,$(SOURCES),$(file)))
PROJ_CPPSRCS = $(filter %.cpp,$(foreach file,$(SOURCES),$(file)))

#|---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
#| Set important path variables                                                          |
#|---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
VPATH    = $(foreach path,$(sort $(foreach file,$(SOURCES),$(dir $(file)))),$(path) :)
INC_PATH = $(INCLUDES)
LIB_PATH = -L$(dir $(RESOURCES_LINKER))

#|---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
#| Options for compiler binaries                                                         |
#|---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|

COMMON_FLAGS = \
-g -O$(OPT)                                                      \
-funsigned-char -fpack-struct -fshort-enums                      \
-Wall -Wstrict-prototypes                                        \
-DMCU=$(MCU)                                                     \
-DMAINCLOCK=$(MAINCLOCK)                                         \
-DSCLFREQ=$(SCLFREQ)                                             \
$(INCLUDES)


ifeq ($(CROSS_COMPILE),avr-)
    COMMON_FLAGS += -mmcu=$(MCU)
    ASFLAGS = -mmcu=$(MCU)
endif

CFLAGS += $(COMMON_FLAGS) -std=gnu99

CPPFLAGS = $(COMMON_FLAGS) -std=gnu++11 -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions

ASFLAGS += -Wa,-adhlns=$(<:.S=.lst),-gstabs -I. -x assembler-with-cpp

LDFLAGS = -Wl,-Map=$(BOARD).map,--cref

#|---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
#| Define targets                                                                        |
#|---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
#AOBJS += $(patsubst %.S,%.o,$(PROJ_ASRCS))
AOBJS = $(patsubst %.s,%.o,$(addprefix $(OBJ_PATH)/, $(notdir $(PROJ_ASRCS))))
COBJS = $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(addprefix $(OBJ_PATH)/, $(notdir $(PROJ_CSRCS))))
CPPOBJS = $(patsubst %.cpp,%.o,$(addprefix $(OBJ_PATH)/, $(notdir $(PROJ_CPPSRCS))))

.PHONY: all clean print_info packaging

all: $(OUTPUT_FILE_PATH)

print_info:
    @echo DEFAULT_GOAL ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    @echo $(.DEFAULT_GOAL)
    @echo VPATH ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    @echo $(VPATH)
    @echo SOURCES -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    @echo $(SOURCES)
#   @echo PROJ_ASRCS ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#   @echo $(PROJ_ASRCS)
#   @echo AOBJS ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#   @echo $(AOBJS)
    @echo PROJ_CSRCS ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    @echo $(PROJ_CSRCS)
    @echo COBJS ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    @echo $(COBJS)
    @echo PROJ_CPPSRCS --------------------------------------------------------------------------
    @echo $(PROJ_CPPSRCS)
    @echo CPPOBJS -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    @echo $(CPPOBJS)
    @echo ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    @echo $(CURDIR)
    @echo $(OUTPUT_FILE_PATH)
    @echo ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

$(OUTPUT_FILE_PATH): $(OBJ_PATH) ../rules.mk ../sources.mk $(HAL_PATH)/Makefile $(AOBJS) $(COBJS) $(CPPOBJS)
    $(AR) -rv $(OUTPUT_FILE_PATH) $(AOBJS)
    $(AR) -rv $(OUTPUT_FILE_PATH) $(COBJS)
    $(AR) -rv $(OUTPUT_FILE_PATH) $(CPPOBJS)
    $(NM) $(OUTPUT_FILE_PATH) > $(HAL_PATH)/$(OUTPUT_NAME)_symbols.txt

#|---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
#| Compile or assemble                                                                   |
#|---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
$(AOBJS): $(OBJ_PATH)/%.o: %.s
    @echo +++ Assembling [$(notdir $<)]
    @$(AS) $(AFLAGS) $< -o $@

$(AOBJS): $(OBJ_PATH)/%.o: %.S
    @echo +++ Assembling [$(notdir $<)]
    @$(AS) $(AFLAGS) $< -o $@

$(COBJS): $(OBJ_PATH)/%.o: %.c
    @echo +++ Compiling [$(notdir $<)]
    @$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

$(CPPOBJS): $(OBJ_PATH)/%.o: %.cpp
    @echo +++ Compiling [$(notdir $<)]
    @$(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

#|---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
#| Output folder                                                                         |
#|---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
$(OBJ_PATH):
    @echo +++ Creation of [$@]
    @-mkdir $(OBJ_PATH)

#|---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
#| Cleanup                                                                               |
#|---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
clean:
    -rm -f $(OBJ_PATH)/* $(OBJ_PATH)/*.*
    -rmdir $(OBJ_PATH)
    -rm -f $(OUTPUT_FILE_PATH)
    -rm -f $(HAL_PATH)/$(OUTPUT_NAME)_symbols.txt
    -rm -rf $(DOC_PATH)

#|---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
#| Dependencies                                                                          |
#|---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
$(OBJ_PATH)/%.d: %.s $(OBJ_PATH)
    @echo +++ Dependencies of [$(notdir $<)]
    @$(CC) $(AFLAGS) -MM -c $< -MT $(basename $@).o -o $@

$(OBJ_PATH)/%.d: %.S $(OBJ_PATH)
    @echo +++ Dependencies of [$(notdir $<)]
    @$(CC) $(AFLAGS) -MM -c $< -MT $(basename $@).o -o $@

$(OBJ_PATH)/%.d: %.c $(OBJ_PATH)
    @echo +++ Dependencies of [$(notdir $<)]
    @$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -MM -c $< -MT $(basename $@).o -o $@

$(OBJ_PATH)/%.d: %.cpp $(OBJ_PATH)
    @echo +++ Dependencies of [$(notdir $<)]
    @$(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) -MM -c $< -MT $(basename $@).o -o $@

#|---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
#| Include dependencies, if existing                                                     |
#| Little trick to avoid dependencies build for some rules when useless                  |
#| CAUTION: this won't work as expected with 'make clean all'                            |
#|---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
DEP_EXCLUDE_RULES := clean print_info
ifeq (,$(findstring $(MAKECMDGOALS), $(DEP_EXCLUDE_RULES)))
-include $(AOBJS:%.o=%.d)
-include $(COBJS:%.o=%.d)
-include $(CPPOBJS:%.o=%.d)
endif


#|---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
#| Module packaging for Arduino IDE Board Manager                                        |
#|---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
packaging: $(OUTPUT_FILE_PATH)

docs:   ( cat $(DOXYFILE) ; echo "OUTPUT_DIRECTORY = $(DOC_PATH)" ; echo "INPUT = $(DOC_SOURCES)" ) | doxygen -
#   doxygen $(DOXYFILE)

%.d:
```

Why clang raise me this?

---

Thank's to @MadScientist
I understand why I have this error, if I print things on my make I got :

```
$make print_info 
DEFAULT_GOAL ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
all
VPATH ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
../../hal/stub/ : ../../src/ :
SOURCES -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
../../src/sys_msg.c ../../src/reception.c ../../src/robus.c ../../src/target.c ../../hal/stub/hal.c
PROJ_ASRCS ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

AOBJS ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

PROJ_CSRCS ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
../../src/sys_msg.c ../../src/reception.c ../../src/robus.c ../../src/target.c ../../hal/stub/hal.c
COBJS ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
../../hal/stub/obj/sys_msg.o ../../hal/stub/obj/reception.o ../../hal/stub/obj/robus.o ../../hal/stub/obj/target.o ../../hal/stub/obj/hal.o
PROJ_CPPSRCS --------------------------------------------------------------------------

CPPOBJS -------------------------------------------------------------------------------

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
/Users/nico/Documents/pollen/Robus/robus/hal/stub
../../hal/stub/libstub.a
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

My mistake come for the for this part of my makefile :

```
PROJ_ASRCS   = $(filter %.s,$(foreach file,$(SOURCES),$(file)))
PROJ_ASRCS  += $(filter %.S,$(foreach file,$(SOURCES),$(file)))
```

I don't want to include all .o because I do multiple compilation, I just want to list the needed files.

I have the same compilation process than [ExperimentalCore-sam](https://github.com/aethaniel/ExperimentalCore-sam/blob/master/module/variants/rules.mk) project.

How can I do that?

Comment: Your for loop `$(foreach file,$(SOURCES),$(file))` is not doing anything; you're saying loop through each word in `SOURCES` and for each one expand it to that word... that's a very resource-intensive way of getting back the original list.  Unless you're trying to do some very tricky double-eval thing.

Comment: Yes this is because I compile different lib with different files version. I don't want to include all objects. I use the same build system as this project : [ExperimentalCore-sam](https://github.com/aethaniel/ExperimentalCore-sam)

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand your comment or what it has to do with mine.  All I'm saying is that `$(foreach file,$(SOURCES),$(file))` is nothing more than a very inefficient way of writing `$(SOURCES)`.  You'll get the same results.  You're looping through the value of `$(SOURCES)` and for each element in the list you're obtaining that same element.

Comment: I should also mention that you never want to list a directory as a prerequisite of any target.  You should remove `$(OBJ_PATH)` as a prerequisite from any target.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can only assume that the variable `AOBJS` is empty.  Following back along where it's created, I can only assume that means that there are no `.s` or `.S` files listed in your `SOURCES` variable.

Why don't you run a single invocation of `$(AR)` and just use the `$^` automatic variable and filter out `.o` files, rather than three different invocations of the `$(AR)` command?

```
$(AR) -rv $(OUTPUT_FILE_PATH) $(filter %.o,$^)
```

*EDIT* To be clear I'm suggesting you change your output target rule to this:

```
$(OUTPUT_FILE_PATH): $(OBJ_PATH) ../rules.mk ../sources.mk $(HAL_PATH)/Makefile $(AOBJS) $(COBJS) $(CPPOBJS)
        $(AR) -rv $(OUTPUT_FILE_PATH) $(filter %.o,$^)
        $(NM) $(OUTPUT_FILE_PATH) > $(HAL_PATH)/$(OUTPUT_NAME)_symbols.txt
```

Or, if you wanted to be more idiomatically correct:

```
$(OUTPUT_FILE_PATH): $(OBJ_PATH) ../rules.mk ../sources.mk $(HAL_PATH)/Makefile $(AOBJS) $(COBJS) $(CPPOBJS)
        $(AR) -rv $@ $(filter %.o,$^)
        $(NM) $@ > $(HAL_PATH)/$(OUTPUT_NAME)_symbols.txt
```

As above I'd definitely remove `$(OBJ_PATH)` from the prerequisites list.

Comment: I do it because I don't want to include all `.o` in this lib the SOURCES list don't contain any .s or .S indeed.

Comment: If the SOURCES list doesn't contain any `.s` or `.S` files, then the value of `AOBJS` will be empty (as we discovered: that's what caused your original problem) so the value of `$(AOBJS)` in the prerequisites list will be empty, and so the value of the `$^` automatic variable will not contain any objects for it.  My change gives you _identical_ behavior to what you had before.

Answer (score 1):

I understand the difference between GCC and Clang.

With GCC if you run an `ar` command with no archive members specified, he just skip the step.
Clang raise an error in this case and stop the build.

To patch it I just check if my list is empty or not :

```
$(OUTPUT_FILE_PATH): $(OBJ_PATH) ../rules.mk ../sources.mk $(HAL_PATH)/Makefile $(AOBJS) $(COBJS) $(CPPOBJS)
ifneq ($(strip $(AOBJS)),)
    $(AR) -rv $(OUTPUT_FILE_PATH) $(AOBJS)
endif
ifneq ($(strip $(COBJS)),)
    $(AR) -rv $(OUTPUT_FILE_PATH) $(COBJS)
endif
ifneq ($(strip $(CPPOBJS)),)
    $(AR) -rv $(OUTPUT_FILE_PATH) $(CPPOBJS)
endif
```

Comment: I really don't understand why you don't want to use my suggested solution below.  It's much, much simpler and it's even more efficient because you only invoke `ar` one time instead of three times.

Comment: Your suggestion is the more generic one, but in my case I have to select my archive members. I run this makefile multiple time with different input files each time. I don't want to add conflicting binaries to this archive.

Comment: See my comment above.  Your makefile will behave identically to mine in all situations.